# installing VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle .bundle Vmware Player

Tags: vmware, bundle, vmware-player

how to install VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle ?

```
chmod +x VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle
./VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle
./VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle: line 302: /tmp/vmis.nMJGsk/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: Permission denied

sed -ne'299,303p' VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle
   # Pass all options the user passed in so that the correct UI type
   # gets set.
   "$installer" --set-setting vmware-installer libconf "$libconf"   \
                --install-component "$source"/vmware-installer      \
```

Comment: @Jonas I have the same problem as well, can't seem to figure it out... Have posted this problem to the [askubuntu exchange](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56031/line-302-permission-denied-error-while-installing-vmware-player-3-1-4) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this one out. It took me a while, but it was one of those silly little things that you wish you'd thought of earlier. I had /tmp mounted with the noexec flag so it couldn't run the extracted installer script from the /tmp folder.

I started bash.
Did an su
Then edited the /etc/fstab to remove the noexec option using vi.
Saved the fstab
Rebooted
Now the installer works :-)

Comment: Cheers mate! Posted this over at Askubuntu and received the same answer, worked perfectly! Don't see how I completely missed this one haha, should've realised when I saw the installer was running from /tmp